# Como ignorar/ocultar Warnings en CSSLint en Atom

Tags: css, plugin, atom-editor

Instale el plugin CSSLint Linter pero no he podido ocultar algunos warnings como IDs, entre otros.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

buscando en internet encontré esto

[Como ignorar Warnings stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189103/how-to-ignore-specific-warnings-outputted-by-the-csslint-extension-for-brackets)

[Documentacion csslint](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/command-line-interface)

Pero realmente no comprendo como hacerlo no puedo encontrar el archivo brackets.json, alguien me ayuda por favor

Subo el archivo `.csslintrc`y nada que funciona. alguna sugerencia
[image: archivo]

Comment: no vas a encontrar brackets.json porque ese es un archivo de configuración del editor Brackets, no de Atom. Posiblemente tengas que buscar el archivo `.csslintrc` o crear uno en la raiz de tu proyecto.

Comment: Ciertamente, que gran error, hasta ahora me doy cuenta, la pregunta tiene el tag Brackets. Ese archivo lo cree y lo coloque en la carpeta principal de mi proyecto y no funciono. hay algo que no entiendo, al referirse la raíz de mi proyecto habla de la carpera de mi página web por ejemplo, ( es decir que si tengo varias paginas, tendría que crear varios documentos?) o la carpeta raiz de atom?

Comment: No sé como es el pluging que usas pero posiblemente haya un archivo `.csslintrc` global que afecte a todos los proyectos que abras con atom, o también pudes poner un archivo `.csslintrc` para un proyecto en concreto

Comment: Parece que hay algunos problemas para configurar linter-csslint: https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-csslint/issues/140
Recomiendan usar el plugin linter-stylelint: https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-stylelint

Comment: Ya lo  instale, pero no funciona, como se configura?

Comment: Lo explica en la página del plugin. Si en las opciones pones "Use standar" utiliza la configuración por defecto, si quieres tu propia configuración tienes que crear un archivo `.stylelintrc` usando el formato de stylelint: https://stylelint.io/